# Is it possible to compare one part of a match with another part?

Tags: python, regex, math

I want to write a regex that matches a bishop move in chess notation like
`B<from><to>`. E.g.`Ba1c3`

`^B[a-h][1-8][a-h][1-8]$` will not work. A bishop should always stay on a diagonal. Means `Ba1c2` is not valid. Is there a way to mathematically compare the `<from>` and `<to>` with regex? Something like `B([a-h])([1-8])\1+1\2+1`. +1 meaning is is exactly one value bigger than the group.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with regex alone, but using regex you may extract the numerical components, and then do the math in Python.

Comment: why you limit the numbers to `8`, but not the letters to `h`?

Comment: You can always enumerate the valid moves: `^Ba1(b2|c3|d4|e5|f6|g7|h8)$`. For matching "all" valid (bishop) moves, you can enumerate them a bit more efficiently by realizing that all diagonals commute, so a valid move from X to Y implies a valid move from Y to X. A valid bishop move on a main diagonal is matched by `^B(a1|b2|c3|d4|e5|f6|g7|h8)(a1|b2|c3|d4|e5|f6|g7|h8)$` , and you'll need some more trickery to eliminate the non-moves where the bishop moves from field X to field X: `^B(..)(?!\1)`. This is easy (but too long for this comment) to put together.

Comment: @Gsk true, corrected

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is definitely the wrong tool to perform this operation; I suggest you to validate the string with an `if/else` condition and list comprehension, then use the regex if the result is valid:

```
import re

move = 'Be4c2'


valid_move = True if ((ord(move[1]) - ord(move[3])) == (int(move[2]) - int(move[4])) and all((0 <= int(x) <= 8 if x.isdigit() else ord(x) -96 for x in move[1:5]))) else False

if valid_move:
    start, stop = re.findall(r'[a-h][1-8]', move)
    print start, stop
else:
    print "Wrong move"
# OUTPUT: e4 c2
```

The regex now is pretty simple.
For the `if` condition, we use `ord()`, which returns the unicode int for the given char:

```
print ord("a") # 97
print ord("b") # 98
print ord("c") # 99
# ...
```

We also know that a bishop can move only on a diagonal, so the difference from the horizontal distance must be equal to the distance of the vertical distance, so in our `if` condition we have:

```
 (ord(move[1]) - ord(move[3])) == (int(move[2]) - int(move[4])
```

We also don't accept number outside the range 1-8 and letters outside a-h, so the numbers should be inside that range and the `ord()` of the chars (`-96`, since `a` is `97`) should also:

```
(0 <= int(x) <= 8 if x.isdigit() else ord(x) -96 for x in move[1:5])
```

If both condition are true, we can apply our regex.

Comment: Sure. This is true. I am aware of that and I did it myself too like you did. But I am learning regex and wanted learn how they are strong.